# $P (A) = P (A\mid B) P (B) + P (A\mid\neg B) P (\neg B)?$

Tags: probability

How to assess using rules of probability, whether the following statement is true or not?

$$P (A) = P (A\mid B) P (B) + P (A\mid\neg B) P (\neg B)$$

Comment: Yes, it is true. Apply definition of conditional probabilities on RHS and then use additivity to see that the equation is true.

Comment: This holds in the "universe" of just two events, $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 5):

$$P(A \mid B)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$$
Hence 
$$P(A \mid\neg B)P( \neg B) = P(A \cap \neg B)$$
Now ask yourself this, what is
$$P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \neg B)$$
According to the Venn Diagram below, you'd get $P(A)$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \Pr (A\mid B) \Pr (B) + \Pr (A\mid\neg B) \Pr (\neg B) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(A\ \&\ B) + \Pr(A\ \&\ \neg B) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr((A\ \&\ B) \text{ or } (A\ \&\ \neg B)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(A).
\end{align}
The fact that $(A\ \&\ B) \text{ or } (A\ \&\ \neg B)$ is true if and only if $A$ is true can be shown by truth tables without knowing anything about probability.